# Adding two different class objects to JavascriptInterface in android

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I wanted to confirm if it ios possible to add 2 different class / interface objects to android's addJavascriptInterface(). Like this :

```
 keyBoard = new KeyBoard(mWebView,context);  
 mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(keyBoard,"keyBoard");  

 mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "external");  
 mWebView.loadUrl(url);  ....
```

Something like this??

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: Hey @smitha, are 2 interfaces working for your use-case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to bind multiple objects to Javascript so that the methods can be accessed from JavaScript.

[addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29)